# Extra underlined char at the end of a link

Tags: html, css

I have two figures (with captions), side by side, and each figure acts as a link. For some reason, the text of the left link has an extra underlined space, even though it doesn't appear in my html file. Could this be a spacing issue? I'm new to CSS, so there might be redundancies/contradictions.

Here's a preview of the problem: [Zoomed image](http://s-j-b.github.io/images/html_bug.png)

```css
#leg {
  text-align: center;
}
#leg_tag {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.leg_link {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="leg">
  <p id="leg_tag">How to reach me:</p>
  <a class="leg_link" href="..." target="_blank">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My GitHub!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class="leg_link" href="...">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My LinkedIn!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

EDIT: The problem has been resolved, but I still am curious as to why the second link does NOT have a space, while the first one does. Ideas?

Comment: do you have a *space* after the first closing `</figure>` and before the closing `</a>` tag?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity nope. Furthermore, when I swap both links (swap the whole linkedin figure with the github figure), the space is in the same place, between the two links. That's why I think it's a layout problem.

Comment: Actually, I removed all spaces between both `</figure>` and both `</a>` and now it works https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/uj40c8s9/

Comment: See my answer for a way to do this without worrying about whitespace.

Comment: the newline character usually adds a white space (That is the sad part).....

Comment: @repzero then why isn't there a whitespace after the second link?

Comment: In fact that is a very good observation....there are many question on SO that highlighted this issue.....I cannot say what happened in the second link..hmm.....me==thinking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the link to be `display: inline-block` and then you can add your `text-decoration: underline`, if desired, to the text itself (`<p>`).

```css
#leg {
  text-align: center;
}
#leg_tag {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.leg_link {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.leg_link figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.leg_link p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="leg">
  <p id="leg_tag">How to reach me:</p>
  <a class="leg_link" href="..." target="_blank">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My GitHub!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a class="leg_link" href="...">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My LinkedIn!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

The reason for this is because `<a>` is an inline element by default, and you have nested inline-block / block level elements inside it, without changing the anchor's display property.

From the [CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level):

> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) are broken around the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes. When such an inline box is affected by relative positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level box contained in the inline box.

Comment: Helpful, thanks! Ideas on why there's a space on the first link but not the second?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some more details, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the second question seems to be due to trailing whitespace before the closing  tag. If you pack this up against the last element, the trailing _ goes away `</figure></a>`

The first link is same as yours, the second is the minimum bad example with one space `</figure> </a>` the third link is `</figure></a>` and doesn't exhibit the trailing _ .

This is surprising to me, as I thought whitespace didn't matter in HTML, and my IDE keeps tidy reformatting the code I fixed!

```css
#leg {
  text-align: center;
}
#leg_tag {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.leg_link {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="leg">
  <p id="leg_tag">How to reach me:</p>
  <a class="leg_link" href="..." target="_blank">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My GitHub!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> </a>
  <a class="leg_link" href="..." target="_blank">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My GitHub!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <a class="leg_link" href="..." target="_blank">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My GitHub!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure></a>
  <a class="leg_link" href="...">
    <figure>
      <img src="..." width="30" height="30">
      <figcaption>
        <p>My LinkedIn!</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```